UseEffect and SetInterval, creating infinite loop and refreshing the session
I want to keep making my request because whenever I add an item to my cart, the carticon which displays the amount of items in the cart has to update. But this keeps refreshing my session, so when I put this to production you it becomes laggy.
I want to solve this by running it maybe once, and not onclick because the components which could be doing this on click, are just not connected with eachother.
export default function Header({ props }) {
const pollingRef = useRef(0);

const [newItemState, setNewItemState] = useState(0);

    const [itemsState, setItemsState] = useState(props.cart);
    let finalquantity = itemsState.map((item) => item?.quantity || 0);
    // console.log(finalquantity);

    
    const updateCartAmount = async () => {
        try {
            let itemQuantities = itemsState.map((item) => item?.quantity || 0);
            let newItemState = itemQuantities.reduce((acc, sum) => acc + sum, 0);
            console.log(newItemState);

            const response = await axios.get('/cartjson');
            setItemsState(response.data);
            setNewItemState(newItemState);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to update cart', error);
        }
    };
    
useEffect(() => {
        pollingRef.current = setInterval(() => {
            updateCartAmount();
            // console.log('polling');
    }, 2000)

    return () => {
        clearInterval(pollingRef.current)
    }
    }, []);

Im using Inertia and i found something about UseRemember but i dont really know if thats something what could solve this. I want to update the quantity but NOT the session tokens

First thing first, I see you create the interval every 2 seconds and it is used to fetch from Api from time to time i believe this is the reason for the lag.
Also I think if you want to update the amount of item in the cart icon you can make the state in the parent or the top of the component instead and pass the count to the component props. So whenever the state updated the component props become updated too.

But the problem is how, My Header is rendered everywhere on the page from app.jsx, i need the function to be everywhere, to pass a function to a component i need to do onRemove={onRemove} for example.

I think you should try to useContext because it is accessible everywhere just by using useContext syntax and you can store variable in there, and i think it is much faster than API

Its accessible in parent and children relations ship, my header which needs to be updated isnt a child or parent, its just a loose component which is used everywhere since its a navbar

If you place contextProvider in the root component then you can access the context from everywhere.

But its not about getting the data, its about pressing a button and on shopitem to add it, and making a request on the same page but in a differenent component and live refreshing the amout of items in the cart, cart is in the header

I think you can make the flow like this. When pressing the button send the request API to the backend -> count the total amount of the item -> update the state in the context -> react will automatically update the component.
This is just my opinion as how to update the cart in the header.
